# django rest framework: include related model fields in same path

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Product
       fields = ('id','product_id','sku', 'title','price','images')

class WishListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      product = ProductSerializer()

      class Meta:
        model = WishList
        fields = ('wishlist_id','product',)
```

I have two serializers. Wishlist and Product. I want to list all wishlist products. It works fine now. But the product details is in "product" key element. Can I remove that product key, and show the product details along with the wishlist_id ?

Present result:

```
 {
      "count": 2,
      "next": null,
      "previous": null,
      "results": [
        {
          "wishlist_id":1,
          "product": {
            "id": 1460,
            "product_id": "04396134-3c90-ea7b-24ba-1fb0db11dbe5",
            "sku": "bb4sd817",
            "title": "Trinity Belt",

          }
        },
        {
          "wishlist_id":2,
          "product": {
            "id": 596,
            "product_id": "52588d22-a62c-779b-8044-0f8d9892e853",
            "sku": "ml346",
            "title": "Martina Liana",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Expected result:

```
    {
      "count": 2,
      "next": null,
      "previous": null,
      "results": [
        {
          "wishlist_id":1,
          "id": 1460,
          "product_id": "04396134-3c90-ea7b-24ba-1fb0db11dbe5",
          "sku": "bb4sd817",
          "title": "Trinity Belt",

        },
        {
          "wishlist_id":2,
          "id": 596,
          "product_id": "52588d22-a62c-779b-8044-0f8d9892e853",
          "sku": "ml346",
          "title": "Martina Liana",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad practice and you need a lot of effort to implement serialization and deserialization, especially in case of Post, Update etc.
I can think of 2 ways.
1) You could use in the WishListSerializer the missing fields as SerializerMethodField
example

```
product_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

 def get_product_id(self, obj):
        return obj.get_product().product_id
```

2)

```
class WishListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.CharField(source='product.product_id')
    .......

    class Meta:
        model = WishList
        fields = (product_id, ......)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could "unnest" items in `to_representation`
docs on it https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields

```
...
class WishListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = WishList
        fields = ('wishlist_id', 'product',)

    # add 
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        flat_data = dict(wishlist_id=data['wishlist_id'], **data['product']) # construct (new dict) flat data 
        # or you could restructure same dict: data.update(data.pop('product')) 
        return flat_data
```